# Google maps info window open() panTo edge of map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

i have these two lines

```
map.panTo(respectiveMarker.getPosition());//Center in map the respective marker
infoWindow.open(map, respectiveMarker);
```

When infoWindow.open is executed the map pans to the edge.
If i remove this line the map pans to the marker as expected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should set disableAutoPan to be true in the InfoWindow and that will stop the map from moving when the infowindow is open.